# TypeError: test.each is not a function in React test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm reading the documentation here for my create-react-app react app:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api.html

`In your test files, Jest puts each of these methods and objects into the global environment. You don't have to require or import anything to use them.`

I have tried copying the Jest `test.each` example code into my test:

```
test.each([[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]])(
  '.add(%i, %i)',
  (a, b, expected) => {
    expect(a + b).toBe(expected);
  },
);
```

When I run my test I get this error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: test.each is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (sorting.test.js:71:6)
          at <anonymous>
```

I have the correct version of Jest:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  }
```

I thought `test` was supposed to be a global, just like `it` - The second test here passes and this is the whole test:

```
import {isValidNumber} from '../sorting';
test.each([[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]])(
    '.add(%i, %i)',
    (a, b, expected) => {
      expect(a + b).toBe(expected);
    },
);

it('Should reject no args', () => {
  expect(isValidNumber(undefined)).toEqual(false);
});
```

What is missing?

Comment: Two years later: Same here `TypeError: each is not a function`.
`node v12.19.0`, `npm 6.14.8`, `jest-each ^26.6.2`. Could you solve your issues?